# can you undo private static jest mock

Tags: typescript, ts-jest

I have a typescript class that look something like this.

```
class MyClass {
  private static async myFirstMethod(): string {
    return await mySecondMethod() + "john";
  }

  private static async mySecondMethod(): string {
    return "hello ";
  }
}
```

I mock the test like this.

```
describe('MyClass', () => {
  describe('myFirstMethod', () => {
    it('make sure myFirstMethod works', () => {
      const mock: Mock = jest.fn();
      MyClass['mySecondMethod'] = mock;

      ... do some testing ...

    });
  });

  describe('myFirstMethod', () => {
    it('make sure mySecondMethod works', () => {
      const value: string = MyClass['mySecondMethod']();
      expect(value).toBe("hello ");
    });
  });
});
```

The problem with testing the class this way is that executing the line `MyClass['mySecondMethod']()` in the second test will invoke the mock instead of calling the method implementation.  This is because the first test replaces the function with mock.  By the time the second test executes, the mock has not been removed from the static method.

I know I can reverse the test execution order, but I would like to find out if it's possible to remove the mock so that it will execute the original function, instead of the mock.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up `saving` the original method in a variable, then resetting it in the second test.  Like this

```
describe('MyClass', () => {
  // Save the original method
  const originalMySecondMethod = MyClass['mySecondMethod']();

  describe('myFirstMethod', () => {
    it('make sure myFirstMethod works', () => {
      const mock: Mock = jest.fn();
      MyClass['mySecondMethod'] = mock;

      ... do some testing ...

    });
  });

  describe('myFirstMethod', () => {
    it('make sure mySecondMethod works', () => {
      // Reset the method
      MyClass['mySecondMethod']() = originalMySecondMethod;

      const value: string = MyClass['mySecondMethod']();
      expect(value).toBe("hello ");
    });
  });
});
```

I still wonder if there is a different way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `jest.restoreAllMocks();` in `beforeEach`?

Comment: I've tried `mockClear()`,` mockReset()`, `mockRestore()`.  None of those work.